# Manually query SHA-1 signature of release key

Tags: android, android-studio, keytool

I tried using:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl base64
```

This didn't seem to work for me as it said:

[image]

What do it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command to get SHA-1 hash of your signing key.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore KEYSTORE_PATH -alias ALIAS_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your Gradle menu in Android studio.
Expand the "Tasks" 
Inside "android", please click on "signingReport"
In you run tab, you will find the SHA-1 key.

Comment: That's not they way to generate releasekey. I already did it!